# Go: Can't unmarshall?

Tags: json, go

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    m["name"] = "Test"

    j, _ := json.Marshal(m)

    fmt.Println(string(j))

    var unmarshalled map[string]string
    _ = json.Unmarshal(j, unmarshalled)
    fmt.Println(unmarshalled)
}
```

Shouldn't `unmarshalled` be filled with the json data `j`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't ignore your errors

```
json: Unmarshal(non-pointer map[string]string)
```

`unmarshaled` needs to be a pointer:

```
err := json.Unmarshal(j, &unmarshalled)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But shouldn't the compiler have told me that?

Comment: It's not a compile time error, it's a runtime error. Unmarshal takes and `interface{}` which can be anything, and it's up to you to provide the correct parameter.